# In Salesforce mobile app, why does my button bring user out of the app and open the component in a browser

Tags: custom-button, android

Button that points to the childComponent is not opening in the Salesforce app (on Android emulator) - it takes the authenticated user to the browser, ask for login instead. I selected "Open with: Salesforce".

```
    handleNav() {
    var compDefinition = {
        componentDef: "c:childComponent",
        attributes: {
            propertyValue: "id"
        }
    };
```

Is it something to do with the device setting? Works fine on an actual iPhone.

Comment: Check that the app is configured to open supported links appropriately. You can access this by pressing and holding the app icon on the homescreen, select the (i) button then tap the "Set as default" option.

Comment: Not sure how you get to this config in the emulator, TBH, but hopefully the same way.